# Why do null topics affect the output of filter logs in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, filters

I'm connected to a private chain with geth and this is the output I get when trying to retreive logs (first topic is function signature):

```
> eth.filter({'fromBlock': 0, 'toBlock': 'latest', address: '0xe25b529f5b2475694eeb29dced46dde986488b03', topics: ["0x8a314ef48dbd2506be5878ac08beae6e006dc0e15052df82217252ba71026059", null, null]}).get().length
6125
> eth.filter({'fromBlock': 0, 'toBlock': 'latest', address: '0xe25b529f5b2475694eeb29dced46dde986488b03', topics: ["0x8a314ef48dbd2506be5878ac08beae6e006dc0e15052df82217252ba71026059"]}).get().length
14286
```

I remember reading that null topics had no effect on log filter output, eg. they only existed in order to enable filtering by specific topics, while leaving others out. But it seems this isn't the case.

This is especially concerning for scenarios in which I need to access logs by the second argument, leaving the first one blank. This seems to only work for recent logs. Anyone has an idea why?